# Why I am getting "Echo is on" when trying to print a variable in batch

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, dos

I tring to excute a simple batch file scripts :

```
echo %1
set var = %1
echo %var%
```

When I am running it in XP, it is giving me expected output, but When I am running it in Vista  or windows 7, I am getting "Echo is On" when trying to print (echo) value.

Below is the output of program :

```
G:\2012>abc.bat 1

G:\2012>echo 1
1

G:\2012>set var = 1

G:\2012>echo
ECHO is on.

G:\2012>
```

Comment: set var=%1 pause output:= C:\>set var= C:\Users\vpatel\Desktop>pause Press any key to continue . . . Does not asked for user inout

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Get rid of the spaces in your set expression. There can and should be no spaces on either side of the equal sign (=)

```
set var=%1
```

BTW: I usually start all my batch files with @echo off, and end them with @echo on too, so I can avoid mixing code with the output of the batch file. It just makes your batch file output a little nicer and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I tried to do an echo without any value and redirect to a file using Python.  Looks to be a hidden troubleshooting feature in the echo command.

Comment: well described behaviour. See `echo /?`

Comment: I typed that on Windows using Gitbash and Linux and the output is '/?' I was using the os.system command in my Python btw. This is the manual for the linux echo command. https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo There is no referance to ECHO ON or ECHO OFF in there.  So it is therefor hidden. Now I'm sure it's documented somewhere on the web but it's far from obvious.

Comment: Well, the question isn't about git or linux, but tagged  `Windows`, `Windows-7`, `batch-file` (which is the Windows command line interpreter) and `dos` (which is a common mistake and should 
 be `cmd`, the Windows command line) Other languages may have a command with the same name, but don't expect it to behave identically.