# Get PID of cmd instance started by a process?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which starts an .exe which, in turn, starts another batch file.
How can I get PID of the later cmd.exe instance?

Comment: By using tasklist, you can even filter on the PID https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html, in your case you might want to filter on the name of the exe

Comment: you can try with [pslist](https://ss64.com/nt/pslist.html) - it can list processes as a list and you can check what was started by the exe.

Comment: do you have control over the second started bat? you can make it to print it's own pid to a file that later you can red

Comment: @npocmake Good idea, I'll try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to do this (save as .bat file and try it)

It lists CMD.exe processes with the time it was started and the PID in the 3rd column so you know the latest one is the one you want! :) (or in this case the one just before the latest one since the latest one is that cmd you run to check the process ID)

```
@echo off&cls
pushd %~dp0

powershell.exe -command "Get-Process | select name, starttime, id | out-file cmdproc.txt"
find "cmd" cmdproc.txt

echo.
pause
rem CLEANUP
del /f cmdproc.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I found this solution which I think is better: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6133. But now I have another problem. When trying to echo the variable %cmdpid%, I get "Echo is on". How can I solve it?

Comment: The "Echo is on" is due to a misplaced space or character somewhere, if you have a SET command make sure there are no spaces near the equal sign (see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328744/why-i-am-getting-echo-is-on-when-trying-to-print-a-variable-in-batch)

Comment: I suggest this code if you want to know the PID and WindowTitle or the current CMD : https://pastebin.com/AZ98y2XH 

You could save the PID and WindowTitle variables to a file or anything else for further processing.